# Avoid nested observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I need to fill in three controls with hierarchic structure: companies, branches, employees.
Out of user service I get currently logged in user,
then via user's domain name I receive his full data as Employee, 
then per employee's branchId I obtain branch object,
then I request all companies and set control values as 
currrent employee, current branch, and current branch's company.

I end up with nested tree of subscribers.
How can I avoid this and refactor it to be more straightforward?

```
this.userService.getCurrentlyLoggedInUser().subscribe(
    user => {
        this.user = user;
        this.getEmployee(this.user.domainName).subscribe(
            employees => {
                if (employees.length === 0) {
                    this.isLoading = false;
                    return;
                }
                this.getBranch(employees[0].branchId).subscribe(
                    branches => {
                        if (branches.length === 0) {
                            this.isLoading = false;
                            return;
                        }
                        this.odata.companies().subscribe(
                            companies => {
                                this.setDefaultValues(companies, branches[0], employees[0]);
                                this.isLoading = false;
                            },
                            error => this.isLoading = false
                        );
                    },
                    error => this.isLoading = false
                );
            },
            error => this.isLoading = false
        );
    },
    error => this.isLoading = false
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid nested subscribe calls you can always map back from a meta branch, such as a stream that has been forked from the main branch through some AJAX call or some other async operation, to a trunk branch by using `mergeMap`.

See the following code for details. Notice, that there is only one subscribe call to the trunk stream. All other streams are `mergeMap`'d back into the trunk stream such that no additional subscriptions are required. Consider subscribing to a stream as breaking out of the RxJS context and get back to normal JS. This should only be required for side effects, such as the `console.log` command.

```
const initialUserObj = { userId: 0, username: 'admin' };

const getUserGroup = function(id) {
  console.log(`Requesting user group for user with id ${id}`); // debug only

  const typeAdmin = { group: 'Administrator', rights: 'all' };
  const typeUser = { group: 'User', rights: 'restricted' };
  const timeout = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Simulated API call with timeout
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(id === 0 ? typeAdmin : typeUser);
    }, timeout);
  });
}

const getUserDetails = function(id) {
  console.log(`Requesting user details for user with id ${id}`); // debug only

  const timeout = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Simulated API call with timeout
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({ fullName: id === 0 ? 'Administator himself' : 'Some User' });
    }, timeout);
  });
}

Rx.Observable.of(initialUserObj)
  .flatMap(user => {
    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(getUserGroup(user.userId))
      .map(group => Object.assign({}, user, group));
  })
  .flatMap(user => {
    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(getUserDetails(user.userId))
      .map(details => Object.assign({}, user, details));
  })
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

[Working sample on jsbin](https://jsbin.com/yeyaru/edit?js,console)

Comment: The difference is that for each subsequent call I need to use info from previous one. Namely, first I get user, then I request organization by user.organizationId. In your example you always you the same userId.

Comment: @avj You're right, I use `user.userId` in both cases, but you can use also all the other values in all subsequent calls. See https://jsbin.com/bakajuh/edit?js,console for an extended example.

Comment: Yes, flatMap worked in the end. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34104638/how-to-chain-http-calls-in-angular2 has simplier example, I used that.