# Angular2 : Http master details calls

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to have some clarifications and helps and about the master details Http calls in Angular2

I already read the answers for how to chain Http calls in Angular2.

[How to chain Http calls in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34104638/how-to-chain-http-calls-in-angular2)
http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/angular-2.0-and-http

In my case the issues are different. For instance I want to retrieve the details of a person inside the SWAPI API and display the details of that persons as well as the details about his movies. Bellow you have what I have done so far and it's not working.

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';


interface Film {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    opening_crawl: string;
    director: string;
    producer: string;
}

interface Person {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    mass: number;
    height: number;
    gender: string;
    films: string[];
}

@Component({
    selector: 'person-details',
    template: '<h3>Details</h3><ul><li><b>Name : </b>{{person.name}} </li><li><b>Mass : </b> {{person.mass}} </li> <li><b>height :</b> {{person.height}} </li></ul>'
    //displaying personnage films
})
export class PersonDetails2Component implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    person: Person;
    sub: any;
    filmdetails: any;
    private baseUrl: string = 'http://swapi.co/api/people/1/';

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        console.log('PersonDetails2Component constructor');
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('ngOnInit');

        this.http.get(this.baseUrl, {headers: this.getHeaders()}).map((res: Response) => {
            this.person = res.json().results.map(toPerson);
            console.log('this.person');
            return this.person;
        })
            .flatMap((person) => this.http.get(person.films[0])).map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .subscribe(res => this.filmdetails = res);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }

    private getHeaders() {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        return headers;
    }
}

function toPerson(r: any): Person {
    let person = <Person>({
        id: extractId(r),
        name: r.name,
        mass: r.mass,
        height: r.height,
        gender: r.gender,
        films: r.films
    });
    console.log('person parsed =', person);
    return person;
}

function extractId(personData: any) {
    let extractedId = personData.url.replace('http://swapi.co/api/people/', '').replace('/', '');
    return parseInt(extractedId);
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: What is the actual behavior? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: Hi, The expected behavior will be to display a personage details as well  the details of the films. Those information are available from the API.   Right now I'm having this message :    EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./PersonDetails2Component class PersonDetails2Component - inline template:0:38 caused by: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined. From my code :  this.http.get(person.films[0])). Also, I don't know how to get all the films ; so I'm gettingonly the first one