# Angular 4 sequential Http.post calls

Tags: javascript, angular, rest

How to make sequential (synchronous) http POST calls (wait the response from each call)

```
generateDoc(project, Item, language, isDOCXFormat) : Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post(this.sessionStorageService.retrieve('backendApi').baseUri + '/export/document/' + project.projectId + '/' + Item.id,
                     {language:language, isDOCXFormat:isPDFFormat}, option);
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to chain Http calls in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34104638/how-to-chain-http-calls-in-angular2)

Answer (score 2):

If you want synchronous calls, you can use `concatMap`:

```
http.post(url1, data1).concatMap(t=> http.post(url2, data2);
```

Comment: seems good, can you give me an example with generateDoc(params) method. Thank you