# Angular (4): Multiple HTTP requests with Observables: one after another succeeds

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I am kind of new to Angular 4 and `Observables` and everything related to it.
I am trying to execute two `http` requests one after another (only **when** the first one succeeds).

I'm using this code:

```
public getCompany(id: string): any {
    let company = null;

    this.authService.isValidUser().subscribe(response => {
      const token = this.tokenStorageService.getTokenFromStorage();
      const requestUrl = environment.gatewayUrl + environment.companyService + environment.getCompanyEndPoint + id;
      const headers = new Headers();
      headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
      const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

      return this.http.get(requestUrl, options).catch(this.errorService.handleError);

    }, (error: AppError) => {
       // ........ //
    });
  }
```

This is the `isValidUser()` method code:

```
  public isValidUser(): any {
    const token = this.tokeStorageService.getTokenFromStorage();
    if (!token) {
      console.log('cannot find token');
      return false;
    }

    const requestUrl = environment.gatewayUrl + environment.authorizationService + environment.userServiceEndPoint;
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
    const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

    return this.http.get(requestUrl, options).catch(this.errorService.handleError);
  }
```

The idea here is to only return `return this.http.get(requestUrl, options).catch(this.errorService.handleError);` after the `authService.isValidUser()` code worked.

I don't think this is a proper way of performing such requests, since my second request is already completed before the first one does.

Maybe I am missing some way on how to do it properly?

Thank you.

Comment: `since my first request is already completed before the second one does` -- this is what you are trying to do, isn't it??

Comment: Uhh my mistake. The second one is completed before the first one completes

Comment: In your code the first one completes before the second one... the result of the first request is the `response`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where is code where you try to chain these two functions?

You can achieve what you want using `switchMap` operator. Here is [docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) for it.

I think you need something like this:

```
isValidUser()
  .filter(isValidUser => isValidUser) // <-- perhaps you need this filter since you want to make getCompany call only if user is valid
  .switchMap(() => getCompany())
  .subscribe(...do something...);
```

Don't forget to add `import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';`. You can also use `mergeMap` or `flatMap` (`mergeMap` is synonim for `flatMap`), but it is not preferred.

As @BeetleJuice mentioned in comments: Why `switchMap` is better? For example, you use mergeMap or flatMap and something caused another call of that code. Even if two first requests was not finished new ones will be sended. It is even possible that second bundle of requests will be finished faster than first one. After that first bundle finishes and you have wrong data in your state. To solve this RxJS provides perfect operator `switchMap`. If you used this operator in situation above then first observable (first request bundle) will be cancelled. Only last observable (from last call) will stay alive. You need switchMap only if you have possibility to run that code several times in a short period of time. If you know that this code will run only once `mergeMap`/`flatMap` will do same for you.

Also, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34107312/2898694).

Update 3/28/2020: With new versions of rxjs, you can no longer call the switchMap operator on the returned Observable. Instead, you need to call pipe on the observable and pass in what should happen afterwards. For example:

```
isValidUser()
  .pipe(
    switchMap(() => getCompany())
  )
  .subscribe(...do something...)
```

Multiple operators can be passed into the pipe function as well. More info can be found on the rxjs site on the [operators page](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators)

Comment: Cool . Then thats the answer.

Comment: Sharikov, @DenissM. `switchMap` is a better option than `mergeMap` because in this use case, you would want to preserve the order of execution -- the second http request should only ever be made after the first one resolves. `mergeMap` allows for the possibility that several requests of the first type are made while a slow second request is over the wire.

Comment: @BeetleJuice I updated. I tried to explain same using my explanation. Do you think everything is correct? Or should I fix?

Comment: Thanks. I think it's correct, but it will be up to the OP to test whether it works in his or her project

Comment: @SharikovVladislav I'll test tomorrow and let you guys know. Thanks a lot! I was thinking about switchMap also, because that one made more sense in my case when I read about it before.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav please fix the import for `switchMap` to `rxjs/add/operator/switchMap;`

Comment: @DenissM. Fixed. Sry.