# Angular4 extracting value from Observable

Tags: angular

I am trying to get value from http.get() and assign it to local variable.

Here is my code. **UserName.ts**

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/user/').subscribe(res => { 
  this.username$ = res;
  console.log(this.username$)}) //working


console.log(this.username$)
```

I am getting **undefined** as output

The http call - **http://localhost:8000/user/**  will return only one username. I have to store it in a variable. And use it to invoke another http call

```
return this.http.get(`http://localhost:8001/getdettails/${this.username$}/${experimentPath}`)
```

Please help me in solving this issue.Thanks.

Comment: Do you understand how asynchronous code and callbacks work ? the last line of your code is executed before your observable returning. So the variable can't be set yet.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34104638/how-to-chain-http-calls-in-angular2

Comment: @Pac0 removed the flag, as I missed the last part of the question (http call chaining)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to make your call when it is ok (for instance : in the callback of your observable).

Currently, your first subscription has not had the time to complete when the last `console.log` line is reached. So, the variable has not yet been set. Only later, when the subscription returns, the callback is executed, and so the  `console.log` in the callback shows some value.

To solve your issue, you *could* make your second http call in the callback of the first subscription, but it is not good practice to nest subscriptions.

(thanks @Jota.Toledo) : You can have a look to this post for better approach using RxJs `mergeMap` to chain the result of your first observable to a second http call :

[How to chain Http calls in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34104638/how-to-chain-http-calls-in-angular2)

In your case, this would result in something like this :

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';

this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/user/').map((res: Response) => {
           this.username$ = res;
           return res;
        })
        .mergeMap(username => this.http.get(`http://localhost:8001/getdettails/${this.username$}/${experimentPath}`)).map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .subscribe(res => {
             console.log('Here is your result from second call:');
             console.log(res);
        });
```

(maybe you will have to adapt slightly, depending on the output)

Comment: No idea who is downvoting.. this is valid

Comment: I downvoted, you suggest the use of a nested subscribe, which is a bad practice. The other answer is the same. Please refer to the linked resource for a clean answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34104638/how-to-chain-http-calls-in-angular2

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Thanks for feedback

Comment: @ Jota.Toledo and thank you for fixing the example with mergeMap as well  !