# Angular RxJS Service wait for the other service result

Tags: angular, service, rxjs, resolver

I have two service svcA, svcB. The svcA result is `Observable<ObjA>`. The svcB result is `Observable<Array<ObjB>>`. The svcA result is the parameter of the svcB.
How can I implement this in a route resolver which result is `Observable<Array<ObjB>>`?

Unfortunately RxJs version is below 5.5

Thanks

Comment: Use switchMap to combine those two into one - svcA.pipe(switchMap(svcAResult => ...))

Comment: As I mentioned RxJs version below 5.5 so pipe not exists because introduced in 5.5. If I remember good. I would like to use the svcA result as parameter in svcB

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular - Make multiple HTTP calls sequentially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51212448/angular-make-multiple-http-calls-sequentially)

Comment: In RXjs below 6, is `svcA.switchMap(res=>svcB(res))` just "remove" pipe, see https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/v6/migration#pipe-syntax

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the observable chain instead of pipe if the version is below 5.5

```
svcA
  .doMyJob()
  .switchMap(resultFromA => svcB.doMyJob(resultFromA))
```