# Angular: How to synchronize two observers in **different places** of the code

Tags: angular, rxjs

**Background**

In an Angular component, I need to load some settings before to load the data, so I have the following code:

```js
  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService,
    settingsService: SettingsService
  ) {
    settingsService.get().subscribe({
      next: (settings) => this.settings = settings
    });
  }

  onInit() {
    this.loadData();
  }

  loadData() {
    this.dataService.get(this.settings).subscribe({
      next: (data) => this.data = data
    });
  }
```

As you can see, `this.settings` has to be loaded **before** to call `loadData()`, which is called in the initialization and subsequently when the user press a button. While `settingsService.get()` is called just once in the beginning, `this.dataService.get()` can be called many times.

**Problem**

The first `loadData()` calling from `onInit()` has been called before `settingsService.get()`  finishes, so the parameter is undefined and I get an error.

**Question**

How do I synchronize them for this particular situation?

**NOTE**

There is a similar question at [Angular - Make multiple HTTP calls sequentially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51212448/angular-make-multiple-http-calls-sequentially), but I believe it is a different scenario, because in that case both observers are called every time together, sequentially. In this particular case, I need to synchronize them only on the first time, so I cannot see how `switchMap` can be used here. I am not a RXJS expert, so if I'm not right, some tip will be welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use *switchMap* to load data from settings first and then call the *dataService.get()* with the result:

```
readonly data$ = this.settingsService.get().pipe(
  switchMap(settings => this.dataService.get(settings))
);

constructor(private dataService: DataService, private settingsService: SettingsService) {}
```

Notice I'm not bothering to use the *ngOnInit()* lifecycle hook, and instead just creating a stream that will be consumed using the async pipe on the template.  This makes the code a lot smaller, and you don't have to go through the effort of unsubscribing from subscriptions in the *ngOnDestroy()* hook.

- If you only want one result, and either of the methods stay open, then you can easily add *take(1)* after the switchMap.
- If there are multiple bindings to *data$* on then template then consider adding the *shareReplay* operator at the end of the stream so multiple underlying calls aren't made.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Gimenez, but I can't see in this example how to make subsequent calls to ```this.dataService.get()``` without to call ```this.settingsService.get()``` together thru the ```data$``` variable

Comment: Under what circumstances do you need to call `this.dataService.get()` again? Do the settings change?

Comment: Hi, @DeborahK, that code is a minimal reproducible example. Actually ```this.dataService.get()``` carries more parameters that depends on user interaction. So, yes, the settings change.

Comment: You could define "action" streams. Here is an article: https://tomastrajan.medium.com/practical-angular-the-most-impactful-rxjs-best-practice-tip-of-all-time-c5d717ec8c4b I have a github example (using pagination instead of settings, but the idea would be the same): https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-ActionStreams Here is a talk on the topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OKZBHuYa-wc

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need here is Subject. See code and explanations below.

```js
  //will be use to trigger if settings api completes
  private settingsReady: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
  
  //make settingsReady as observable so we can subscribe to it
  private settingsReady$: any = this.settingsReady.asObservable();
  
  //mock the settings api that will be executed after 5 sec
  private settingsApi$ = of('settingsApi').pipe(
    delay(5000),
  );
  
  //mock the data api that will be executed after 2 sec
  private dataApi$ = of('dataApi').pipe(
    delay(2000),
  );
  
  constructor() { 
    //trigger the settings api
    this.settingsApi$.subscribe((result: any) => {
      console.log('settingsApi execute after 5 seconds =>', result);
  
      //inform settingsReady subject that setting api already complete
      //##KEY_PART you can also pass the result of the api here
      this.settingsReady.next(result);
    });
  }
  
  ngOnInit() {
    //will only trigger once settings api complete
    //that is when settingsReady call next on ##KEY_PART
    this.settingsReady$.subscribe((settingsResult) => {
      console.log('settings result from Subject =>', settingsResult);
      this.loadData();
    });
  }
  
  loadData() {
    //trigger the data api
    this.dataApi$.subscribe((result) => {
      console.log('dataApi execute after settingsApi completes =>', result);
    });
  }
```

Result of above code:

```
> settingsApi execute after 5 seconds => settingsApi
> settings result from Subject => settingsApi
> dataApi execute after settingsApi completes => dataApi
```

**Note**: On some case, you may want to trigger loadData immediately without waiting for the settings api to return value initially. For such scenario, you may look into **BehaviorSubject**.

Answer (score 0):

Use the power of observables. [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) will ensure that first observable completes first

```
constructor(
    private dataService: DataService,
    settingsService: SettingsService
) {}

onInit() {
    this.loadData();
}

loadData() {
    this.settingsService.get().pipe(
        switchMap(settings => this.dataService.get(settings))
    ).subscribe(data => {
        // do something
    })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use repeatWhen:

```js
    private reload$ = new Subject<void>();
    
    constructor(
        private dataService: DataService,
        settingsService: SettingsService
    ) {}
 
    onInit() {
        settingsService.get()
            .pipe(
                switchMap(settings => this.dataService.get(settings).pipe(repeatWhen(() => reload$))),
                
            ).subscribe({next: (data) => this.data = data});
    }

    reloadData() {
        this.reload$.next();
    }
```