# RxJS - chaining multiple observables and doing other stuff in between

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've looked a lot online and haven't been able to find anything that describes my problem.

I'm currently using Angular 5.

Basically, I want to perform a `put` http request, then once that complete do some stuff, then perform another `get` http request and do some more stuff.

Here is my code using nested subscriptions (which I know you shouldn't be doing):

```
this.projectService.updateProject(this.project).subscribe(
  subscribe => {
    doSomethingAfterTheUpdate();
    this.projectService.get(this.id).subscribe(
      subscribe => {
        doSomethingAfterTheGet();
        });
    });
```

As you can see, I am updating the project, then getting the project. How can I do this properly using RxJS. I've looked into Concat and MergeMap methods, but I want to perform some action after both the update and the get.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to chain Http calls in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34104638/how-to-chain-http-calls-in-angular2)

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I don't think it is a duplicate; the difference is I want to perform some action after executing the first http request AND execute another http request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider the `doSomethingAfterTheUpdate` a side-effect, so you could go as:

```
import { mergeMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.projectService.updateProject(this.project).pipe(
   tap(_ => this.doSomethingAfterTheUpdate()),
   mergeMap(_ => this.projectService.get(this.id))
).subscribe(_ => this.doSomethingAfterTheGet());
```

Note that I use `_` on some pipe operations, as you dont really use the scoped values.

Comment: Thanks! I actually do need the scoped value from the `this.projectService.get` method. My question is, what if I do another `tap` after the `mergeMap` instead of doing a `subscribe` at the end, what would be the difference, as I have tested this out and it works the same as the subscribe.

Comment: @Viqas Your original code snippet does not reflect that. Moving the callback from the subscribe into a 2nd `tap` after `mergeMap` would not make a difference.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use operators [tap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html) and [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) to achieve this:

```
import { switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

// ...

this.projectService.updateProject(this.project)
  .pipe(
    tap(() => doSomethingAfterTheUpdate()),
    switchMap(() => this.projectService.get(this.id)),
    tap(() => doSomethingAfterTheGet())
  )
  .subscribe(results => console.log(results));
```

Hopefully that helps!