# How to call multiple apis call one after another

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am learning `RxJS`. I have 3 api call's, I need to make 2nd api call, and pass it's data as a parameter to 3rd api call. I tried this:

```
    checkPermission(permissionName: string): Observable<boolean> {
    this.check(this.p1)
      .pipe(
        switchMap(res => {
          const shouldCheck = res.Value;
          if (shouldCheck.toLowerCase() === 'true') {
            return this.checkPermission(permissionName).pipe(
              map(result => {
               
                return result;
              })
            );
          } else return of(true);
        })
      )
      .subscribe(permission => {
       
      });       
    }
```

But getting syntax error.

Comment: @AdrianKokot where to place that bracket, i am not able to understand

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34104638/how-can-i-chain-http-calls-in-angular-2

Comment: I just want to send the data got from 2nd api to 3rd api as a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted is not very comprehensible, but I'll try to make something usable out of it:

```
  checkPermission(permissionName: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.checkSetting(this.p1).pipe(
      map((res) => res.SysConfig.Value.toLowerCase() === 'true'),
      switchMap((shouldCheck) =>
        iif(
          () => shouldCheck,
          this.permission(this.p2).pipe(
            switchMap((data) =>
              this.hasPermission(permissionName, data.SysConfig.Value)
            ),
            // hoping that res.permission is a boolean
            map((res) => res.permission)
          ),
          of(true)
        )
      )
    );
  }
```

You should also omit the `subscribe` if you plan on returning `Observable<boolean>`. You can subscribe to the observable returned by this method in the place where you call it:

```
this.authService.checkPermission(permission).subscribe(hasPermission => {
  console.log(`User ${hasPermission ? 'has' : 'does not have'} ${permission} permission`);
});
```

Comment: I just updated working and non working code. please check

Comment: I am facing one serious issue, please check your chat

Answer (score 1):

Try it,  I have not tested though.

```
   checkPermission(permissionName: string): Observable<boolean> {
      return this.checkCompanySettingForPermission(this.p1)
          .pipe(
            switchMap(res => this.permissionAPI(res, permissionName)),
            tap(permission => this.$permissionSub.next(permission)),
            switchMap(_=> this.$permissionSub.asObservable())
          )
     }
    
    permissionAPI(res :any, permissionName: string): Observable<any>{
        const shouldCheck = res.SysConfig.Value;
        if (shouldCheck.toLowerCase() === 'true') {
           return this.permissionAPI2(permissionName);
        }
        return of(true);
    }

  permissionAPI2(permissionName: string) :Observable<boolean>{
    return this.checkCompanySettingForPermission(this.p2).pipe(
       switchMap(data => 
        this.hasPermission(permissionName, data.SysConfig.Value).pipe(
              map(( {permission})=>permission)
            )
        )
     );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `switchMap` operator in proper order i.e.

```
.pipe(
    switchMap(() => {
        return this.someFunctionThatReturnsObservable();
    }),
    // here you will have access to data you've returned in previous (in data variable)
    switchMap((data) => {
        return this.someOtherRequest(data.param1, data.param2).pipe(
            map(result => {
              return result.permission;
            })
        );
    })
)
```

Remember that you need to place rxjs operators one after another in pipe separating them with coma. Problem is that you have incorrect syntax trying to put some code without operators inside pipe, these lines are problem here:

```
return this.permission(this.p2).pipe(
    const shouldEncrypt = res.SysConfig.Value;
```

It is not fully clear what exactly you want to do here, but I assume that you want to conditionally return request or empty observable, you need to add operator before placing above code.

Comment: I just updated working and non working code. please check