# If `of` necessary when returning previous response with mergeMap?

Tags: angular, rxjs6, rxjs-observables

I am chaining HTTP calls as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/34107312/470014
however I only want to execute the next call if the previous one returns null. So I have the following code:

```
public getTolerances() {
  this.queryServer(12,34).pipe(
    mergeMap(previous => {
        if (previous) {
            return of(previous);
        } else {
            return this.queryServer(0,34);
        }
    }),
    mergeMap(previous => {
        if (previous) {
            return of(previous);
        } else {
            return this.queryServer(34,0);
        }

    }),
    mergeMap(previous => {
        if (previous) {
            return of(previous);
        } else {
            return this.queryServer(0,0);
        }
    })
  )
  .subscribe((result) => {
      console.log({result});
  });
}
```

If the previous call returns a result I am using `of` operator to return that as an observable. Is that necessary or is there a way I can drop them? It feels like I am unwrapping the promise and then wrapping it up again but if I just return `previous` I get the following type error:

> Argument of type '(result: unknown) => unknown' is not assignable to
> parameter of type '(value: unknown, index: number) =>
> ObservableInput'.   Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type
> 'ObservableInput'.ts(2345)

Comment: For the type error that's straightforward and the compiler is correct since result's type and the operator argument's type are not compatible. Curious, when you do: if (previous) does you know by default that previous is nullish or it is typo, since if you want to check whether it is nullish or not it should be if (!previous)

Comment: @onrails ok, thanks for the confirmation. I know it's null if no answer is returned as I wrote the backend too. If it's truthy (not null) then I return the result of the previous http call. Otherwise (else) I query the next potential value. If I use !previous I would have to reverse the clauses. Admittedly I could remove the `else` and just `return` in the mainline code, in which case it might make more sense to invert the `if` statement as you suggest...

Comment: Go it! So in other words you want to skip the current  API endpoint call to the next call based on a supplied predicate ?

Comment: @onrails erm I think so. I only want to make the next call if the current/previous call returns null. Are we saying the same thing, just in different words? Maybe there is a better way of doing this in RxJS?

Comment: Yep, with RxJs switchMap you can have something similar to what is above.        
  mySourceObservable
  .pipe(
    switchMap(val => {
      if(val === a) { return Obs1 }
      else if(val === b) { return obs2 }
      else { return Obs3 }
    })
  ).subscribe();

Comment: @onrails Could you post that as an answer please so I can see the formatting properly and give you the kudos if it works.